# Efecto boton presionado en android

Tags: android

Tengo 4 botones y a todos le quiero dar un efecto presionado pero quisiera saber si puedo crear 4 códigos diferentes en un solo Resource File o tengo que crear 4 Resource File para cada botón este es el código de un resource file que lleva como nombre "animaboton.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnpress" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnsinpress"></item>
```

en el XML lo mando a llamar
`android:background="@drawable/animaboton"`

Answer (score 0):

Una vez creado el Resourse file solo tienes que llamar el `android:background="@drawable/animaboton"` en los botones que quieras